# how often do I find A in a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database. In a certain column I have some letters ex: 'xxadbia'. 
I want to extract the number of times the letter a occur in this table.

In this example my query must return 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `length` function to do it as

```
mysql> select ( length('xxadbia') - length(replace('xxadbia','a',''))) as cnt ;
+-----+
| cnt |
+-----+
|   2 |
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it:

```
SELECT 
    letters,    
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(letters)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( letters, "A", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH("A")        
    ) AS count    
FROM temp_EM8
```